# ¿Como puedo ver el tiempo de ejecución de un código en Ruby?

Tags: date, ruby, cmd

Digamos que mi código se llama HolaMundo.rb y se ve así:

```
class HolaMundo
    def initializae()
    end
    def saluda()
    puts "Hola Mundo"
    end
end

objeto = HolaMundo.new()
objeto.saluda
gets()
```

Quisiera ayuda para saber como saber el tiempo de ejecución del código en Ruby desde que le doy a ejecutar hasta que me muestra el mensaje "Hola Mundo". Estoy usando Sublime Text 3 para modificar el código y el CMD para visualizar el "Hola Mundo". Ya he investigado en internet pero no hay nada que se acerque a lo que busco

Answer (score 1):

Me parece raro lo que pides, ya que son contextos distintos. Uno es el proceso que ejecuta el programa, lo cual puedes medir con [time](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_(Unix)):

```
$ time ruby HolaMundo.rb
Hola Mundo
ruby HolaMundo.rb  0.09s user 0.05s system 5% cpu 2.480 total
```

Lo otro es el contexto de ejecución dentro de ruby, donde puedes usar [benchmark](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html):

```
  require 'benchmark'

  class HolaMundo
    def saluda
      puts 'Hola Mundo'
    end
  end

  puts(Benchmark.measure { HolaMundo.new.saluda }) 
  #   0.000020   0.000012   0.000032 (  0.000027)
```

Pienso que una opción mixta sería que pasaras como parámetro desde la consola un timestamp que envíe info con precisión de milisegundos. Puedes [revisar aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548528/command-to-get-time-in-milliseconds) unas opciones de como obtenerlo dependiendo si estás en Linux u Osx. Luego ejecutas algo como:

```
ruby HolaMundo.rb $(gdate +%s)
```

Y por el lado ruby recuperas el valor con `ARGV`, para usarlo como sustraccion de `Time.now`

```
# Aquí mostraría con precisión de segundos cuanto se demoró desde que se
# ejecutó el programa hasta que se llamó a esta línea.
puts Time.now.to_i - ARGV[0].to_i
```